# Conditional JOIN using field data

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have the following tables:

**dog**: `id, name, event_id` which is used to store dogs

**event**: `id, title, owner_id` which is used to store events like birthday, vaccines, etc

**owner**: `id, name` which is used to store owners. The original owner is a kennel which has an id of `1`

**owner_event**: `original_owner_event_id, other_owner_event_id` which is used to equate various owner events to each other, i.e. the original owner might consider a "walk event" equal to the other owner's "play catch" event.

---

Joining everything:

**dog** joins **event** where `dog.event_id = event.id`

**owner** joins onto **event** where `event.owner_id = owner.id`

*Here's the tricky part*:

When `owner_id > 1` then **event** joins **owner_event** where `owner_event.other_owner_event_id = event.id`

Otherwise, **event** joins **owner_event** where `owner_event.original_owner_event_id = event.id`.

---

So far I have the following:

```
SELECT * FROM dog
LEFT JOIN event `event` ON `event`.id = dog.event_id
LEFT JOIN owner `owner` ON `owner`.id = `event`.owner_id
LEFT JOIN owner `owner_event_other` ON `owner_event_other`.other_owner_event_id = `event`.id AND `owner`.id > 1
LEFT JOIN owner `owner_event_original` ON `owner_event_original`.original_owner_event_id = `event`.id AND `owner`.id = 1
WHERE dog.id = 3
```

I'm just not sure how to actually get the `event.title` now for dog `3` (for example).

Bearing in mind that it could be the `event.id` from `owner_event.other_owner_event_id` column or `owner_event.original_owner_event_id` column depending on the `owner.id`.

Comment: You join `owner` three times. I suppose the last two should read `owner_event` instead.

Comment: It is not exactly clear which output you want. Do you want to see the event title as listed for that dogs owner, or do you want the original owner's event title always. Please provide some sample input for all tables and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As only one of the two possibilities can exist for a given `owner` record, I would suggest to only join `owner_event` once, but chain `event` a second time to it in order to retrieve the title via the original owner's event (in case the directly  retrieved `event` record does not represent that title. With `COALESCE` you can then pick the right title.

```
SELECT    dog.*,
          COALESCE(original_event.title, event.title) AS original_event_title 
FROM      dog
LEFT JOIN event 
       ON event.id = dog.event_id
LEFT JOIN owner 
       ON owner.id = event.owner_id
LEFT JOIN owner_event
       ON owner_event.other_owner_event_id = event.id
LEFT JOIN event original_event
       ON original_event.id = owner_event.original_owner_event_id
WHERE     dog.id = 3
```

Comment: I know this might be a shot in the dark but for some reason when I uncomment the `LEFT JOIN owner_event` part then I get back additional records which shouldn't be there. This might be due to the fact that **owner_event** contains the same `original_owner_event_id` value for various `other_owner_event_id` fields. When `original_owner_event_id` is to be used, `other_owner_event_id` tends to be `0`.

Comment: Can you explain why you actually need that table to be included in the SQL? Which information from that table do you actual use?

Comment: I always want the `event.title` associated with `owner_event.original_owner_event_id`. The issue comes in when `event.id` is not found in `owner_event.original_owner_event_id` because it's in `owner_event.other_owner_event_id`. So sometimes I need to find the `owner_event.original_owner_event_id` value that correlates with `owner_event.other_owner_event_id`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it

Comment: You're welcome. Appreciation can be expressed by upvoting ;-)